# How use annotation for given xml in hibernate java

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have following code in xml,how could i use annotation for below code

```
     <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.gf.DataDetail" table="DATADETAIL">

    <id name="DataId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="DATA_ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="recordId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="RECORD_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="recordName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="RECORD_NAME"></column>
    </property>

               <set name="detail" table="DETAIL" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="DATA_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.gf.detail" />
    </set>

  <set name="loadErrors" table="LOADERRORS" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="DATA_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.gf.loadErrors" />
    </set>
</class>
```

and in java file i have

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "DATADETAIL")

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BatchMetaData {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ID")  
    private Number DATA_ID;

    @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")  
    private Number RECORD_ID;

    @Column(name = "RECORD_NAME")  
    private String RECORD_NAME;         

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "DATADETAIL")
    private Set<DETAIL> detail = 
            new HashSet<DETAIL>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "DATADETAIL")
    private Set<LOADERRORS> loadErrors = 
            new HashSet<LOADERRORS>(0);



    public Set<DETAIL> getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
    public void setDetail(Set<DETAIL> detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
    public Set<LOADERRORS> getLoadErrors() {
        return LoadErrors;
    }
    public void setLoadErrors(Set<LOADERRORS> LoadErrors) {
        this.LoadErrors = LoadErrors;
    }
```

I am just converting from xml file to annotation file here.Am i applying oneto mapping annotations in wrong place.Any suggestion on this.

Comment: what did you try? "Please give me code" is not how this site works

Comment: @JimHawkins Please look updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent name")`

`mappedBy` should be parent object name.

Comment: should i use '@joincolumn' for DATA_ID column as they are using key tag in xml file

Comment: Detail table is the relationship owner in the xml that you have shared.     So mappedBy is alone sufficient as it indicates that parent object is not going to control the relationship

Comment: According to explaination i am having more than one table with key tag in xml ,if so should i use joincolumn annotation.Please check my updated query , if wrong in that please correct in that.